# How to autogenerate username and password in createuserwizard?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How to autogenerate username and password in createuserwizard vb.net !

I want username as int data type and auto increment as 1000, 1001, 1002 and so on ...

and password for all user in random numbers ... with characters as aA123Sb

in createuserwizard complete step it will show username and password....

how to do in vb.net ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, instead of letting the user enter the user name and password you want to create it all programmatically?

If so, I don't think you want to use `CreateUserWizard` since you don't need to have the actual user interface, instead I think you want to look at [Membership.CreateUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/library/system.web.security.membership.createuser.aspx).

To create the username, all you'll need to do is to remember the last username and then increment it. The password is a little bit more difficult but here's an article with a couple of suggestions for doing this: [Generating Random Passwords with ASP.NET](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020102900/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/101205-1.aspx)

Answer (score -2):

```
Function CreateUsername(ByVal UserFirstname, ByVal UserLastname)
    ' create username
    Dim UsernamePrt1 = UserFirstname

    Dim TempUsernamePrt2 = UserLastname
    'find length of string 
    Dim LengthLN = TempUsernamePrt2.Length

    Dim UsernamePrt2 As String
    If LengthLN <= 4 Then
        UsernamePrt2 = TempUsernamePrt2
    Else
        UsernamePrt2 = TempUsernamePrt2.Substring(0, 4)
    End If

    Dim R As New Random
    Dim UsernamePrt3 As Integer = String.Concat(Enumerable.Range(4, 4).Select(Function(n) R.Next(0, 10)))

    Dim FullUsername = UsernamePrt1 & UsernamePrt2 & UsernamePrt3

    Return FullUsername

End Function
```